# I am getting multiple inputs in this format (x,y) in a string, and converting it into integers

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemJ3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Corr; //Integer will be used to input x and y coordinates in arrays.
        int DropsOfPaint = input.nextInt(); //Getting the total number of coordinates needed.

        //Creating arrays to hold x and y values.
        int ArrayOfCorrX[] = new int[DropsOfPaint];
        int ArrayOfCorrY[] = new int[DropsOfPaint];

        //asking user for a number of x and y coordinates, depending on DropsOfPaint.
        for ( int i = 0; i <= DropsOfPaint; i++ ) 
        {
            String[] parts = new String[DropsOfPaint];
            Corr = input.nextLine();
            parts = Corr.split(",");
            System.out.println(parts.length);
            int num1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
            int num2 = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
            ArrayOfCorrX[i] = num1;
            ArrayOfCorrY[i] = num2;
        }
        //Setting initial value before maximum and minimum number search.
        int MinX = ArrayOfCorrX[0];
        int MaxX = ArrayOfCorrX[0];
        int MinY = ArrayOfCorrY[0];
        int MaxY = ArrayOfCorrY[0];

        //Compares and saves a new minimum or maximum each time if there is available option.
        for ( int j = 0; j < DropsOfPaint; j++ ) 
        {
            if (ArrayOfCorrX[j] < MinX) MinX = ArrayOfCorrX[j];
            if (ArrayOfCorrX[j] > MaxX) MaxX = ArrayOfCorrX[j];
            if (ArrayOfCorrY[j] < MinY) MinY = ArrayOfCorrY[j];
            if (ArrayOfCorrY[j] > MaxY) MaxY = ArrayOfCorrY[j];
        }
        //Out puts size of canvas from bottom left corner to top right corner.
        System.out.println((MinX - 1) + ", " + (MinY - 1));
        System.out.println((MaxX + 1) + ", " + (MaxY + 1));

        input.close();
    }
```

I keep receiving this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at ProblemJ3.main(ProblemJ3.java:24)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What are the arguments you passed on running the class?